# Using jQuery Validate rules to mark required fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I've implemented the jQuery validation plugin from bassistance.de and use it by manually defining rules below each form I'd like to have validated. 
I would like to modify the fields (eg. give them a border-color) that I defined as required after the script initialisation is done, but I can't seem to find a generic 'loaded' callback, event or extending possibilities.

**Is there a way to perform a script each time that `$('#form').validate(..)` is finished initializing?**

The way I'm solving it right now is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myForm').validate({
        rules: {
            txtCode: { required: true, maxlength: 12 },
            txtName: { required: true, maxlength: 50 },
        }
    });
    $('#myForm').highlightRequiredFields();
});
```

.. where `highlightRequiredFields()` is a simple jQuery plugin I wrote to modify the required textboxes. I'm just not so keen on duplicating that line to all my form validations.

Comment: Hi Leon. I am not familiar with the plugin that you used, but you may be able to achieve this through an implementation of the `.promise()` method (which is fairly new). I must caution you, however, to review the documentation thoroughly if you haven't used it before - there are a few catch-22s to the method. Also, the `.promise()` method will help you to start your actions after ALL actions on the collection have completed.

Comment: Can you use `validate`'s option `submitHandler` to run your highlight function? (instead of submitting the form) http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options

Comment: Thanks guys. @Chase, I would like to highlight the fields even before submitting, so the `submitHandler` wouldn't work for me. @Zachary, the `promise` method doesn't provide a way to add a generic handler to the script as far as I know?

Comment: Correct, you will not be able to use it to add a generic handler to the script, but you can use it to determine when the script is done running on the collection and then call another method after it using the `.done()` method. From your question, it was my understanding that you were attempting to add a handler once the initialization was complete; you can add the handler from within the `.done()` method. Did I understand you correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone. Zachary's respond made me realise it's much easier than I thought. 
I ended up adding this overload:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        validateAndMarkRequired: function(options) {
            var validator = this.validate(options);
            this.markRequiredFields();
            return validator;
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply do you're changes with CSS? I have a bunch of rules & even a few JS lines that run automatically on anything that  has the class of **required**, and once they are valid / error, other things (that I want) happen to them.

Otherwise you'd have to most likely make changes inside of the `$.fn.validate()` plugin itself.

Comment: As I said in my comment above, I'm not familiar with the validation plugin that he's using, but if all he's looking to do is add support for a CSS change on callback couldn't he simply add an overloaded call to the plugin that calls the "built-in" `$.fn.validate()` and calls his CSS change immediately after?

Comment: Thanks! I can't do the changes with CSS since I prefer to add the rules manually, not by adding classes. And the plugin doesn't add 'required'-classes when I add these rules manually.. It seems like I really have to insert the code to the plugin script..

Answer (score 1):

I would interfere with init method of validate plugin to execute your highlightRequiredFields plugin.

Do not forget to check is this plugin available, so validate would not break if uses without highlight somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for responding! Putting it inside the init function is my final call indeed.. I'd rather not have it in the plugin script since it gets overriden when a colleague decides to put a new version of it to the project for example. That's why I was wondering if there's a better method :)